# How do I structure HTML/CSS/Javascript so that people who have never worked with HTML/CSS/Javascript can work with it?

Tags: model-view-controller, frameworks, client-side, convention

I've been working with HTML/CSS/Javascript + any server side code (ASP, JSP, PHP, Ruby on Rails) for my entire engineering life. I really don't need structure to figure out how something works in order to fix/extend/improve it. But, I don't work by myself.

I work with people with diverse skill sets, including some who have never touched (or even seen) HTML/CSS/Javascript in their lives.

A simplified cross section to help glimpse the HTML/CSS/Javascript experience:

- a layer of people who have never viewed source.
- a layer of people who think inspect element is the same as view source.
- a layer of people who know to find some non image, non background-image, non input field, non flash object, piece of real estate on the webpage to right click for a menu and then select "view source".

How do I structure the HTML/CSS/Javascript so that people who have never worked with HTML/CSS/Javascript can take a feature request, find the pieces of code it touches, and proceed?

What can be done, and where should I start? Where should the code start? Is there a basic and simple convention that one can follow?

Comment: I think you have to create some directory conventions first. Ex: The `html` files should be in the `/html`directory. The CSS files in `/css` and so on ...

Comment: Yes, we're working with Ruby on Rails, so the files all exist in the right directories (as it pertains to RoR). It's just that there's trouble understanding the life cycle of UI components.

Should it be assumed that the engineers have a basic understanding of Javascript to DOM interaction?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your CSS and JavaScript in separate files where possible as this will help programmers coming from non web based languages.

I think it is more about well structured concise code with meaning full variable names and function names.

Also write about twice as many comments as you think you should.

I recently transitions from c# to web based stuff and these steps would have helped me a lot.

Comment: Ah, but if you view source on Twitter, you'll see that they conserve http requests by printing the Javascript into the HTML.

Comment: Yes in some cases you will need to apply a little common sense but as a rule of thumb I think this stands

Answer (score 0):

HTML code should go in a `html` file, JavaScript should go in a `js` file and so on. This way you keep all of your code separate. It means when so work need doing on a JavaScript function the developer will know exactly where to go. It also means for people how are new to web development they will know what the language is they are looking at. I hope this works for you.

Comment: But if you have 40 Javascript files (compressed and minified on production of course) for the various features.  How does one make the code less confusing? Where should someone begin to look for where one feature starts, and another feature ends?

Answer (score 0):

If the people don't know HTML/CSS/Javascript, they must learn it  before working with those concepts.

EDIT:

It will depends on your objective.
Separated files for each content type (css/js/html/images) are useful to increase the maintenability.

Sometimes, you will need to put some inline css/embedded js to achieve performance benefits.

The most important is that the team members follows a convention.

Comment: I disagree I am language agnostic and have to work with different languages on a daily basis. The trick is well structured well commented code.

Comment: You are language agnostic, but you don't put your hands in a thing that you don't know. Or do you do?

Comment: Do you have any advice on what would be considered "well structured" code? "Well commented" is moot, or depends on the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @tocco - due to commercial pressures I often have too look fix code in languages I have never seen.

Comment: Does the code that you tend to have a particular common pattern? Is it UI feature rich? If I had a form like Facebook's "status" form, how would the non HTML/CSS/Javascript engineer know where to look for the backing HTML/CSS/Javascript code?

Comment: @Sheik Yerbouti, Can you do those fixes in the best way? If not, I think that you are doing workarounds ...

Comment: I guess it depends on the intuition of your engineers. Certainly I am not suggesting that it is going to be easy for your engineers, but if you keep functions small, well names and well comented in your js files and have a well defined naming convention for your html elements you will make things far less hellish for them.

Comment: @tocco, I do my work to the best of mu abilities, if I suspect there must be a better way of doing something I research it and find out. Coding is the easy part designing and maintaining working designs is the hard part of software engineering

Comment: @Sheik, I don't think that coding is easy. Well commented, readable, reusable, performatic and correct code it's not so easy to implement in any language. But I have to agree that "designing and maintaining working designs" is hard too ...